# React native freshchat loading issue while implementing show Conversations

Tags: chat, freshdesk

I have installed the react-native fresh chat package and set up the initial configuration. So I need open the conversation widget on the app.

```
Freshchat.showConversations(conversationOptions);
```

I tried the above code to show conversation but I getting a widget with a loader inside it. Loader not stoping.

Please help to fix this issue. Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding:

```
var freshchatConfig = new FreshchatConfig(APP_ID, APP_KEY);
freshchatConfig.domain = "YOUR-DOMAIN";
freshchatConfig.teamMemberInfoVisible = true;
freshchatConfig.cameraCaptureEnabled = true;
freshchatConfig.gallerySelectionEnabled = true;
freshchatConfig.responseExpectationEnabled = true;
freshchatConfig.showNotificationBanner = true; //iOS only
freshchatConfig.notificationSoundEnabled = true; //iOS only
freshchatConfig.themeName = "CustomTheme.plist"; //iOS only
freshchatConfig.stringsBundle = "FCCustomLocalizable"; //iOS only
Freshchat.init(freshchatConfig);
```

> Reference:
> https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/50000000467-freshdesk-messaging-react-native-sdk-integration-steps#Pre-Requisites%C2%A0